# C# AWS lambda calling an HTTP end point randomly gives BadGateway

Tags: aws-lambda

I have a C# AWS Lambda that is calling back to a server with the result of it's work using HttpClient SendAsync.

Sometimes it works fine, other times, having processed exactly the same payload so the call back will be the same it results in a BadGateway.  As far as I know I have no further logs available to me as to why.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Bad Gateway (HTTP 502) are caused by an error happening on the server that you are connecting to. To trouble shoot you need to have access to that servers web server logs to check what error the web server is having when trying to process the request from your Lambda. What could cause it from the Lambda side is maybe the Lambda is scaling too fast and the web server cannot handle it - if that is the case try to reduce your lambdas concurrancy.

Comment: @TobievanderMerwe - spot on, digging deeper on the server I found an error that actually caused the server to die, but docker was bringing straight back up again.  Not sure why it worked sometimes yet.  If you want put something in I can mark as the answer...

Comment: Tom, thanks for your feedback. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Bad Gateway (HTTP 502) check the server logs first that you are connecting. It is a server side error so the logs would be a good place to look first. Also with Lambda check that the Lambda scaling is not creating too many connections that makes the web server give issues.